# How do I launch AppCode from the terminal?

Tags: terminal, appcode, launching

I know that you can quickly launch PyCharm to work on a particular Python project directory by just doing:

`charm directory`

In this case, the `charm` command lives in `/usr/local/bin`.

But can do you do the same of AppCode, pointing it to a `.xcodeproj` or `.xcworkspace` file/?

Comment: `charm` seems to be a special case: it's a purpose written Python launcher script. Appcode on the other hand cannot rely on the fact that Python is installed on the system (despite a system Python always being available on Mac...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the standard OS X 'open' command: 'open -a AppCode.app --args ...'. Please see the manual [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html).

Answer (score 1):

Appcode has built-in terminal tool. In the menu, select

Tools -> Create Command-line launcher...